# Either do or did

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I don't think if anything is wrong in the following sentence

> **Do** you know how old were you when you came here?

But according to my book **do** should be replaced with **did**

I don't understand why?

Comment: What is the book?  Questioners often write "My book" or "I read...".  Please don't do that unless you are able to tell us what the book is.  If it is a text book and it provides *literally no explanation* then the book is obviously worthless.  If it does provide some explanation, but you don't understand it, please quote the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Either "Do" or "Did" but they have different meanings. Before explaining that difference the rest of the sentence needs improving, the middle part should be "you were".

"Do you know how old you were when you came here?" asks about their current knowledge. It asks about what they know today about their age when they first "came here".

"Did you know how old you were when you came here?" suggests that they now know their age but previously, when they first "came here", they may not have known their age.

I have added "first" because I infer that the first time is implied by the sentence. It may be that after arriving they never left and so the "first" is not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is actally being asked. "Do you know (now) how old you were when..." Or "did you know (then) how old you were when... In other words one is about what you know now, when the question is being asked, and the other is about what you knew then, when you came here.